# al crear un proyecto, solo me aparece "Solución (0 proyectos)"

Tags: visual-studio

Al crear un nuevo proyecto, en el panel de la derecha solo me aparece "Sólución (0 proyectos)" pero yo ya tengo un proyecto, solo que por alguna razón no me lo guarda. Desearía saber como solucionar este problema ya que no me deja ejecutar los códigos :(

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. ¿Debes crear una solución y dentro de la solución un proyecto. Es así como lo estás haciendo? Por otro lado, decir "no me lo guarda", sin decir qué mensaje de error aparece o qué pasa exactamente no ayuda mucho a figurarse cuál puede ser tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

El error se puede solucionar borrando todos los archivos caché de la carpeta
/AppData/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio , también borra los archivos caché de la carpeta en la misma ruta pero en vez de ser VisualStudio la carpeta a ingresar debe ser VisualStudioServices.